# Which part is the tail of the letter "r"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage, typography

I'd like to ask about the sentence from A Case of Identity by Conan Doyle.

> "a slight defect in the tail of the ‘r.’ "

Which part is the tail of "r"?
A: The lower part of the straight line of "r".
B: The curving part.

My dictionary says the tail of something" means sometimes the lower part of the thing. But in "r" the curved part looks more like a tail to me.
Does the expression mean different depending on who you ask? Or for native speakers, it's obvious?  Can anyone tell me? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, and there are several ways to hand-write lower-case _r_ (or it may have been upper-case, depending on the context).

Comment: [Here's an example](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fw8k8r3u3.map2.ssl.hwcdn.net%2Fpost%2Fimages%2F09-overlap-pieces.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Ffontbundles.net%2Fblog%2Fask-a-font-creator-using-letter-parts-to-add-flourishes-to-your-words&docid=kSk9-MLeDExjQM&tbnid=casE6mMXHQ4KWM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiAto3-yIrlAhV9SxUIHSppCKQQMwiJASgpMCk..i&w=1000&h=824&bih=906&biw=1475&q=capital%20letter%20%2B%22R%22%20flourish%20tail&ved=0ahUKEwiAto3-yIrlAhV9SxUIHSppCKQQMwiJASgpMCk&iact=mrc&uact=8) of what I'd call "a slight defect" in the "tail / flourish" of a (capital) **R**.

Comment: @Cascabel: Actually, the context is very specifically talking about a worn ***typewriter***. But I wouldn't stake my life on it being the *lower-case* "r" as transcribed - more likely a capital letter, which does have a line that most of us would instantly identify as the "tail" even without a calligraphic "flourish".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Then I guess we need to edit to provide that information...I was unaware of that context.

Comment: I'd say the most common letter after the words *tail of the letter* would be ***Q*** (dunno if it's significant that ***queue*** is French for ***tail***). And since *that* "tail" is a downward-sloping line in the bottom right of the overall space occupied by the letter, I'd naturally look for the nearest equivalent in the letter "r" - which obviously only normally occurs within a *capital* **R**.

Comment: This isn't really a question about the English language, but about typographic terminology, and as such might be better-suited to [GraphicDesign.SE].

Comment: Was it the *print* or *cursive* “r”? The cursive form has a lot more of a tail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In typography, the tail is the descending, often decorative stroke on the letter Q or the descending, often curved diagonal stroke on K or R. The descender on g, j, p, q, and y are also called tails.

Here's a quote from  Eric Gill (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Gill) in his *Essay on Typography*:

> - A typically moral and conscientious Englishman finds it exceedingly difficult to keep morals out of art talk; he finds himself inclined to think e.g. that R ought to have a bow more or less semi-circular and of a diameter about half the height of the stem, & a strongly outstanding tail; that an R with a very large bow and hardly any tail at all is *wrong*.

Pages 50 and 51 of his Essay illustrate his point with all kinds of faulty tails on Rs: https://monoskop.org/images/8/8d/Gill_Eric_An_Essay_on_Typography.pdf